# Set player's main region depending on location - Python

Tags: python, list

I'm fairly new in Python and I could use a bit of advising with a small text-based game (actually a version of the "Risk" board game). I'm having trouble with my location system, because I want to divide the game in regions, and within these there will be a number of locations. I have to do it this way because some regions are not available at first.

Anyway, up till now I made:

A list with the regions (names are sort of procedurally generated):

```
regionList = [casia, lorus, mehin]
```

3 lists for the regions, eg:

```
casia = ["casia", "town1", "town2", "town3"]
```

(I seem to have to leave the name of the region at the beginning of the list for practical convenience in other parts of the code)

And 1 list with the initial position of the player which is updated when the user types in the new location:

```
playerPos = [(regionList[0])[0], (regionList[0])[1]]
```

Is there a way to simply input the name of the location (they are all different) and automatically updating the region in the position list? I haven't found a way to get the name of a list from an element of it, but would that solve it?

Also, if there's a more efficient way to organise it, please inform me, and if the question requires further clarification just tell me.

Many thanks!

Comment: means you want to add new `region` in `regionList` and also update `town` list of `region` automatically.  And from these information we have to update player position so input for player position are `player name`, `region` and `town`. If region information is missing then update region information ?

Comment: I shouldn't have to input both the 'region' and the 'town' that the player goes to because the 'region' will always be depend on the town, eg. if player is in "town1", he will have to be in region "casia". What I don't know is the code "technique" or argument to get the name of the region from the town input , and then transfer the region to 'playerPos'

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think the problem that you're encountering with having to keep the name in the list is perhaps unfamiliarity with object orientation in Python. When you do eventually finish the project consider posting to StackExchange Code Review for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sufficiently few, sufficiently small lists, you may use the brute force solution:

```
def find_location(location_name):
    for region in regionList:
        if location_name in region:
            return [region[0], location_name]
    # if we get there the location name was found nowhere
    raise ValueError('Location {!r} unknown'.format(location_name))
```

If the numbers or lengths of regions slow this brute-force operation excessively for your purposes, you can do a once-off pass to build a dictionary used as an "index":

```
loc2reg = {}
def populate_loc2reg():
    for region in regionList:
        for location_name in region:
            loc2reg[location_name] = [region[0], location_name]
```

This is a bit redundant as it stores the location name again, but it does make things very fast:

```
def find_location_fast(location_name):
    try: return loc2reg[location_name]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('Location {!r} unknown'.format(location_name))
```

There are several possible variants here, I'm just proposing the simplest possible code for starters.